# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel with methods - is it "legal"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Should viewmodels be limited to only have properties, and not methods?

Let's say I have a radio button in my view, and wants to see if the radio button should be checked.

I could do this entirely in my view:

```
@Html.RadioButton("radiobuttonName", "The value", (id == Model.PersonId))
```

or I could move this logic into the viewmodel:

```
@Html.RadioButton("radiobuttonName", "The value", Model.IsChecked(id)
```

using this method in the viewmodel:

```
    public int PersonId { get;set;}
    public bool IsChecked(int id)
    {
        return (id == PersonId);
    }
```

Is this OK to do, or should it be done entirely in the view, or in some other way?

Comment: The practice is - If it compliments the view then yes it is fine. BUt that can be stretched out a long way too :) As long as it does what you need it to do in a consice way. Don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have methods in your `ViewModel`. If it's a single result you want to calculate each time then I'd suggest adding the evaluation code to your `Controller` and storing the result in the `ViewModel` instead but if you need to evaluate things using a method more dynamically and a Property can't do this for you then doing this in the `ViewModel` is probably fine.

In your example above I'd recommend doing this in the `ViewModel` as then the `ViewModel` contains the logic in a single place rather than doing this many times copy and pasted in your `View`.

Comment: It is said that no logic should exists at all in the ViewModel. That best coding practice. But it is nice functionality to have the viewModel update all its properties on a postback by calling a function to do that. (Business logic is separated though. Only Linq and getting data) I realised that if you DONT declare a property in your view that data WONT get sent to the client, period. So it is "protected" - Just be careful what and how you expose properties :)

Answer (score 8):

That's a really good question regarding the correct placement of logic. Your approach is certainly *legal* - but does it follow the spirit of MVC? :)

I'd say it depends on whether the logic in your method applies just to this View/ViewModel, or could be potentially applied to other ViewModels that deal with this underlying Model type (in your case, *Person*).

If this is a one-off calculation for the purposes of this specific ViewModel, keep it in the Model. If this calculation might be used for *Person* objects generally, consider using a static Service class e.g. `PersonService`, and place your methods there.