# ViewModel should have only properties?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm a bit confused about `ViewModel`, in particular I don't understand if is possible add method inside this or the scope of the `ViewModel` is include only the properties for bind the data of the model to the view. So consider this implementation of a `CountryVM`:

```
public class CountriesVM : ViewModel
{
    public AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>> Countries { get; set; }

    public void GetCountries()
    {
        Countries = new AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>>();

        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var countries = Soccerway.Scraper.Countries.GetCountries();
            foreach (var country in countries) 
            {
                var nation = new CheckedListItem<Country>();
                nation.Item = new Country { Name = country.Name, Link = country.Link };
                Countries.Add(nation);
            }
        });
    }
```

so essentially in the *ViewModel* I've a metdho called `GetCountries()` that is called at application startup, this will populate the `Countries` `ObservableCollection`. But I notice that some examples on the net have only properties in the `ViewModel`. 
In each `ViewModels` I inherit the `ViewModel` class that is the base class that contains the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
So my question is:

is my implemenation correct? Or, where the method that I need to call should be placed for valorize the properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC ViewModel with methods - is it "legal"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734925/asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-with-methods-is-it-legal)

Comment: @Set So I need to create something like Controllers?

Comment: The MVC ViewModels are entirely different ViewModels. No connection here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is my implemenation correct?

Yes, certainly as far as MVVM is concerned. 
The VM is supposed to handle the UI logic, just like the Controllers in MVC.

You could consider moving this to a Services layer, but your GetCountries() is on the fence. It's mostly UI related, so I would leave it here.

Comment: what is a Services Layer?

Comment: Look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32224997/60761). In that picture it's called the business layer.

Comment: @hHenk Holterman is correct create a folder Business and put another folder inside it called Controller with the business layer logic?

Comment: No, no controllers in MVVM. Add a class CountrieService to hold the non-UI logic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to ViewModels in MVVM; these are two fantastic references that really helped me understand MVVM:

[Understanding the basics of MVVM design pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/)

[Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)

To answer your question directly, yes you do place methods in the View Model that contain business logic.

Edit:
And then the shortest possible summary I can come up with:

- View - UI
- ViewModel - UI Logic and bindings between View & Model.
- Model - Data models and data access.

Comment: The ViewModel should _not_ do the business logic. But the distinction buisness/ui logic is rather difficult to make at first.